# How to initiate a Java object with a variable?

Tags: java, object, dynamic, instance

I am trying to initiate an object "rational number" that stores a numerator `p`, a denominator `q` and their ratio `r`. This code yields incorrect answer.

```
class Rational { 
    int p, q;
    double ratio;

    public Rational(){
        this.p = 0;
        this.q = 1;
        this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
    }

    public static void main (String[]arg)  {
        Rational r1 = new Rational();

        r1.p = 1;  
        r1.q = 7;
        // r1.ratio = r1.p/(double)(r1.q);    //"this line"
        System.out.println (r1.p  + "/" + r1.q + " = " + r1.ratio) ;
    }
}
```

Uncommenting "this line" solves the problem. How to define object so that `this.r` is automatically updated each time `this.p` or `this.q` is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding this constructor to your Rational class:

```
public Rational(int p, int q){
this.p = p;
this.q = q;
this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the easier way is to define a function named ratio, not a variable.

```
class Rational { 
private int p, q;


public Rational(){
  this.p = 0;
  this.q = 1;
}

public double ratio(){
  return (double)p/(double)q;
}

//define the getters and setters for p and q
}
```

and then whenever you want the ratio you should call the method : 
myRational.ratio()

Comment: You should use `return (double) p / (double) q;` to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 3):

Best bet in most cases is to make class Rational immutable, so that you don't have to deal with inconsistent states and don't need to add logic to update derived fields when the state change. That is, you want another Rational? Just construct it. Period. It would look something like this:

```
class Rational { 
  final int p;
  final int q;
  final double ratio;

  public Rational(int p, int q){
    this.p = p;
    this.q = q;
    this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
  }

  public static void main (String[]arg)  {
    Rational r1 = new Rational(1, 7);
    System.out.println (r1.p  + "/" + r1.q + " = " + r1.ratio) ;
  }
}
```

Bonus, you can make fields private and expose them using getters, for a more encapsulated design.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Rational { 
    int p; 
    int q;
    double ratio;

    public Rational(){
        this.p = 0;
        this.q = 1;
        this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
    }

    public void setP(int p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
    }   

    public void setQ(int q) {
        this.q = q;
        this.ratio = this.p/(double)(this.q);
    }   


    public static void main (String[]arg)  {
        Rational r1 = new Rational();

        r1.setP(1);  
        r1.setQ(7);
        System.out.println (r1.p  + "/" + r1.q + " = " + r1.ratio) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a method for updating them for example

```
public void Update(int p, int q)
{
    this.p = p;
    this.q = q;
    this.ratio = p/q;
}
```

You have to call  it where you are changing p and q values now and delete those two lines.
This should solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating your ratio variable after seting p and q, so ratio stays 0. You should make use of encapsulation.

It should be like this:

```
class Rational { 

    private int p, q;
    private double ratio;

    public Rational(){
        this.p = 0;
        this.q = 1;
        updateRatio();
    }

    private updateRatio() {
       ratio = p / (double)q;
    }

    public setQ(int q){
       this.q =q;
       updateRatio();
    }

    public getQ(){
       return q;
    }

//make getters and setters for variable p too

    public getRatio(){
        return ratio;
    }

    public static void main (String[]arg)  {
        Rational r1 = new Rational();

        r1.setQ(1);
        r1.setP(7);
        System.out.println (r1.getQ()  + "/" + r1.getP() + " = " + r1.getRatio()) ;
    }
}
```